# Haskell make groupBy shorter

Tags: haskell

```
groupBy(\x y -> foo x == foo y)(sortOn foo a)
```

How to make this code shorter? `(\x y -> foo x == foo y)`- I think it's possible to make this part shorter

I have only one Import

```
import Data.List
```

Comment: If `foo` is expensive to compute, consider something like `map (map (\(Arg _ b) -> b)) . group . sort . map (liftA2 Arg foo id)` which is longer but computes `foo` about a third as many times.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Data.Function.on`:

```
groupBy ((==) `on` foo) (sortOn foo a)
```

Comment: I can import only Data.List(

Comment: That's a pretty artificial constraint; `Data.Function` and `Data.List` are both in `base`.

Answer (score 4):

You can make it a little bit shorter by using [the `on` combinator](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.25/base-4.13.0.0/Data-Function.html#v:on):

```
groupBy ((==) `on` foo) (sortOn foo a)
```

But you'd have to import it from `Data.Function`, which makes the overall amount of code greater.

Comment: I can import only Data.List

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of the [**`extra`** package [Hackage]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra) and work with [**`groupOn :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [[a]]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.8/docs/Data-List-Extra.html#v:groupOn):

```
import Data.List.Extra(groupOn)

groupOn foo (sortOn foo a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sacrifice readability for two more characters, you can go the pointfree route and replace `\x y -> foo x == foo y` with:

```hs
(. foo) . (==) . foo
```

Sometimes it's fun to play around with http://pointfree.io/ :).